# Android - EditText appearance - box vs underline

Tags: android, android-edittext

New to android, this may be a simple answer but I cant find the answer for the life of me (maybe I am googling the wrong thing?)

When I am using an EditText, it appears as a White box. How do I get it to be just a line? Examples below. I have tried making the background transparent , but that doesnt seem to quite work. Target API is 18, minimum is 14.

What I get:

[image: get]

What I want:

[image: want]
<sub>(source: [coderzheaven.com](http://coderzheaven.com/uploads/images/seterror.png))</sub>

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your application's (or activity's) theme?

Comment: @CommonsWare Ahh that did it. Changed it to Holo Light. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, while googling i saw this [edittext issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22920)

and yes @commansWare comment is true. change your app theme to Holo Light. this will help you.